# Embed YouTube Videos Using <object> in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, video, iframe, youtube

A site I am working on currently displays YouTube videos using the `<object>` tag as follows:

```
<object width="425" height="353">
    <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/Sagg08DrO5U">
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
    <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/Sagg08DrO5U" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" wmode="transparent" width="425" height="353">
</object>
```

This was implemented about about 7 years ago, and I am wondering whether this is currently considered an appropriate method.

I should note that old requirements for the site stated that iFrames were to be avoided, but I know that iframes are currently the official manner in which youTube prefers one embed videos.

What are the pros/cons to the way I outlined above, and what are the pros and cons of the iframe method (or is this a non-issue)?

Ideally the decision I land on will be html5 appropriate and also appropriate for cross-device compatibility.

Comment: object was more semantic, but iframes have a lot more features these days. the code above actually the <embed> fallback, and that seems a little old-fashioned these days...